# PHPWord_Template save to client

Tags: codeigniter, phpword

I have download the package PHPWord_0.6.2_Beta.zip from [this site](http://phpword.codeplex.com/releases/view/49543)
There are 2 directory : Examples and PHPWord, and 1 file : PHPWord.php
I put PHPWord directory and PHPWord.php in application/third_party and create new library named 'Word.php' in application/libraries as explained in [this article](http://www.ahowto.net/php/creating-ms-word-document-using-codeigniter-and-phpword)
Here is the new library code Word.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

require_once APPPATH."/third_party/PHPWord.php"; 

class Word extends PHPWord { 
    public function __construct() { 
        parent::__construct(); 
    } 
}
?>
```

Now we can easily use PHPWord as CI library
I have tried Text Example from directory Example in downloaded package, here is the original code

```
<?php
require_once '../PHPWord.php';

// New Word Document
$PHPWord = new PHPWord();

// New portrait section
$section = $PHPWord->createSection();

// Add text elements
$section->addText('Hello World!');
$section->addTextBreak(2);

$section->addText('I am inline styled.', array('name'=>'Verdana', 'color'=>'006699'));
$section->addTextBreak(2);

$PHPWord->addFontStyle('rStyle', array('bold'=>true, 'italic'=>true, 'size'=>16));
$PHPWord->addParagraphStyle('pStyle', array('align'=>'center', 'spaceAfter'=>100));
$section->addText('I am styled by two style definitions.', 'rStyle', 'pStyle');
$section->addText('I have only a paragraph style definition.', null, 'pStyle');



// Save File
$objWriter = PHPWord_IOFactory::createWriter($PHPWord, 'Word2007');
$objWriter->save('Text.docx');
?>
```

And I tried implement it in my CI controller, here is the code PHPWord_Text.php

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit ('No direct script access allowed');
class PHPWord_Text extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('word');
    }
    function index() {
        $PHPWord = $this->word; // New Word Document
        $section = $PHPWord->createSection(); // New portrait section
        // Add text elements
        $section->addText('Hello World!');
        $section->addTextBreak(2);
        $section->addText('I am inline styled.', array('name'=>'Verdana', 'color'=>'006699'));
        $section->addTextBreak(2);
        $PHPWord->addFontStyle('rStyle', array('bold'=>true, 'italic'=>true, 'size'=>16));
        $PHPWord->addParagraphStyle('pStyle', array('align'=>'center', 'spaceAfter'=>100));
        $section->addText('I am styled by two style definitions.', 'rStyle', 'pStyle');
        $section->addText('I have only a paragraph style definition.', null, 'pStyle');
        // Save File / Download (Download dialog, prompt user to save or simply open it)
        $filename='just_some_random_name.docx'; //save our document as this file name
        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'); //mime type
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$filename.'"'); //tell browser what's the file name
        header('Cache-Control: max-age=0'); //no cache
        $objWriter = PHPWord_IOFactory::createWriter($PHPWord, 'Word2007');
        $objWriter->save('php://output');
    }
}
?>
```

Access it in

```
http://localhost/codeigniter/index.php/PHPWord_Text
```

Foilaa!!! my code works! But... I'm a bit confused when i tried to translate Template Example in directory Examples from downloaded package into a new CI controller, here is the original code of Template.php

```
<?php
require_once '../PHPWord.php';

$PHPWord = new PHPWord();

$document = $PHPWord->loadTemplate('Template.docx');

$document->setValue('Value1', 'Sun');
$document->setValue('Value2', 'Mercury');
$document->setValue('Value3', 'Venus');
$document->setValue('Value4', 'Earth');
$document->setValue('Value5', 'Mars');
$document->setValue('Value6', 'Jupiter');
$document->setValue('Value7', 'Saturn');
$document->setValue('Value8', 'Uranus');
$document->setValue('Value9', 'Neptun');
$document->setValue('Value10', 'Pluto');

$document->setValue('weekday', date('l'));
$document->setValue('time', date('H:i'));

$document->save('Solarsystem.docx');
?>
```

Can anyone please help me with this problem? please.. T_T
**NOTE** : i dont want it to be saved in server, i want it to show download dialog prompt user wether to save it or open it, works like some code down here

```
// Save File / Download (Download dialog, prompt user to save or simply open it)
$filename='just_some_random_name.docx'; //save our document as this file name
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'); //mime type
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$filename.'"'); //tell browser what's the file name
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0'); //no cache
$objWriter = PHPWord_IOFactory::createWriter($PHPWord, 'Word2007');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Comment: What is the problem exactly? I've seen that you copy & pasted code from the examples given on github & you did not explain what's the problem nor provided the template you'll be using to check it out.

Comment: please re-check my question, i have modified it, hope you understand my question now ^_^

Comment: so the problem is "You don't want it saved on the server" or something else? Please provide the template file you're using in this example (upload it somewhere).

Answer (score 2):

I think you may be experiencing more than one issue with Template.php.

First, you may be trying to figure out what it is doing.

With the other examples x.php produces x.docx.  In the case of Template.php, it uses Template.docx to produce Solarsystem.docx.

The variables Value1, Value2, Value3, etc. are all defined within Template.docx as ${Value1}, ${Value2}, ${Value3}, etc.  If you change the values on the right in Template.php, it will change the corresponding values in Solarsystem.docx.

Second, you seem to be concerned with output.

What works for me is this:

```
$filename = 'nameOfFile.docx';
$document->save($filename);
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-type: application/force-download');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($filename));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($filename));
readfile($filename);
```

This way still saves it on the server but downloads it too.  If I use both `$document->save();` and `$objWriter->save();` I get a blank document when I try to use `readfile();` on the file saved by objWriter.

Answer (score 1):

I thing this is correct :

```
 $filename = 'nameOfFile.docx';
    $document->save($filename);
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-type: application/force-download');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($filename));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-Length: '.filesize($filename));
    readfile($filename);
    unlink($filename);
```

Answer (score 0):

Method `save()` of `Template` class returns name of temp file document, so you just give it to user with `readfile($tempName)`;

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure I get your question correctly, so excuse me if I'm wrong.

In your 4th code block you've got a line

```
$document->save('Solarsystem.docx');
```

If you don't want to save the file to the local disk, but instead send it to the client, you'll just have to remove that line and add the code from the 5th code block:

```
// Save File / Download (Download dialog, prompt user to save or simply open it)
$filename='just_some_random_name.docx'; //save our document as this file name
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-        officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'); //mime type
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$filename.'"'); //tell browser what's the file name
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0'); //no cache
$objWriter = PHPWord_IOFactory::createWriter($PHPWord, 'Word2007');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

require_once APPPATH . '/src/PhpWord/Autoloader.php';

use PhpOffice\PhpWord\Autoloader as Autoloader;
Autoloader::register();
```

Comment: please give some details on how this solves the issue